# How to fix an issue that works with a single node, but fails with 2-node cluster?

Tags: java, session, cluster-computing

I have a redirection issue with a search page. When the application is running on 2 node cluster, the request fails and  redirects back to the search page. On single node it works and moves to the list of search objects.

Since this is on Weblogic, we have checked the server and stdout logs, but not seeing any errors in both places.

The present environment is Apache as web server and Weblogic managed nodes as the application server where the Java code is deployed.

I am trying to investigate, and I am not able to even pinpoint to which log to start the investigation from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely something is stored in a / the session. By default session-state is not replicated across nodes.

Depending on framework you use you might have different options, using spring-session-jdbc would make sense of you use Spring.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-jdbc.html

Maybe you could also look into applying some sticky session mechanism.

Comment: With me being the infrastructure support/middleware services support engineer, I possibly couldn't check that. How can I show the dev that the issue lies in his application and not Weblogic or Apache.

Comment: If it works with one node disabled (in the same setup) you have your prove, IMHO. From an infrastructure perspective you could solve it by doing sticky sessions in some form, maybe cookie based or based on source-ip.